# how i can get number of user hits from IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7

I want to get number of user at time for my site in IIS 7.0. Is there any ways to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to figure out how many people have come to your site, you can enable logging in IIS and then parse the logs to get the number of unique visitors.

If you're asking how to get the number of current users (connected users) on your site at any given time...you're out of luck. IIS itself doesn't do it.

You could try something like [IIS Reporter](http://www.iisreporter.com/default.aspx) (quick Google search turned that one up) which looks like it can "poke" IIS and get the data you're looking for.